# How to convert this html, css and js to a svelte format with style lang="postcss" (for tailwind)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, svelte

I'm trying to convert this sparkle button from a codepen that I found into a svelte component, but when I do it some how the sparkles dont show. Not sure if it matter but im using tailwind css as well, so my style tag has attribute lang="postcss". Here's the codepen I got these from: https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/LYJMPBL These are what makes up the button:

HTML:

```
<div class="sparkle-button">

  <button>
    <span class="spark"></span>
    <!-- <span class="spark"></span> -->
    <span class="backdrop"></span>
    <svg class="sparkle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M14.187 8.096L15 5.25L15.813 8.096C16.0231 8.83114 16.4171 9.50062 16.9577 10.0413C17.4984 10.5819 18.1679 10.9759 18.903 11.186L21.75 12L18.904 12.813C18.1689 13.0231 17.4994 13.4171 16.9587 13.9577C16.4181 14.4984 16.0241 15.1679 15.814 15.903L15 18.75L14.187 15.904C13.9769 15.1689 13.5829 14.4994 13.0423 13.9587C12.5016 13.4181 11.8321 13.0241 11.097 12.814L8.25 12L11.096 11.187C11.8311 10.9769 12.5006 10.5829 13.0413 10.0423C13.5819 9.50162 13.9759 8.83214 14.186 8.097L14.187 8.096Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
      <path d="M6 14.25L5.741 15.285C5.59267 15.8785 5.28579 16.4206 4.85319 16.8532C4.42059 17.2858 3.87853 17.5927 3.285 17.741L2.25 18L3.285 18.259C3.87853 18.4073 4.42059 18.7142 4.85319 19.1468C5.28579 19.5794 5.59267 20.1215 5.741 20.715L6 21.75L6.259 20.715C6.40725 20.1216 6.71398 19.5796 7.14639 19.147C7.5788 18.7144 8.12065 18.4075 8.714 18.259L9.75 18L8.714 17.741C8.12065 17.5925 7.5788 17.2856 7.14639 16.853C6.71398 16.4204 6.40725 15.8784 6.259 15.285L6 14.25Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
      <path d="M6.5 4L6.303 4.5915C6.24777 4.75718 6.15472 4.90774 6.03123 5.03123C5.90774 5.15472 5.75718 5.24777 5.5915 5.303L5 5.5L5.5915 5.697C5.75718 5.75223 5.90774 5.84528 6.03123 5.96877C6.15472 6.09226 6.24777 6.24282 6.303 6.4085L6.5 7L6.697 6.4085C6.75223 6.24282 6.84528 6.09226 6.96877 5.96877C7.09226 5.84528 7.24282 5.75223 7.4085 5.697L8 5.5L7.4085 5.303C7.24282 5.24777 7.09226 5.15472 6.96877 5.03123C6.84528 4.90774 6.75223 4.75718 6.697 4.5915L6.5 4Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <span class="text">Generate Site</span>
  </button>
  <div class="bodydrop"></div>
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="particle-pen">
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg><svg class="particle" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
    --transition: 0.25s;
    --spark: 1.8s;
}

body {
    --active: 0;
    background: hsl(
        260
        calc(var(--active) * 97%)
        6%
    );
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
    transition: background var(--transition);
    overflow: hidden;
}

button {
    --cut: 0.1em;
    --active: 0;
    --bg:
        radial-gradient(
            40% 50% at center 100%,
            hsl(270 calc(var(--active) * 97%) 72% / var(--active)),
            transparent
        ),
        radial-gradient(
            80% 100% at center 120%,
            hsl(260 calc(var(--active) * 97%) 70% / var(--active)),
            transparent
        ),
        hsl(260 calc(var(--active) * 97%) calc((var(--active) * 44%) + 12%));
    background: var(--bg);
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.9em 1.3em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.25em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow:
        0 0 calc(var(--active) * 6em) calc(var(--active) * 3em) hsl(260 97% 61% / 0.75),
        0 0.05em 0 0 hsl(260 calc(var(--active) * 97%) calc((var(--active) * 50%) + 30%)) inset,
        0 -0.05em 0 0 hsl(260 calc(var(--active) * 97%) calc(var(--active) * 60%)) inset;
    transition: box-shadow var(--transition), scale var(--transition), background var(--transition);
    scale: calc(1 + (var(--active) * 0.1));
}

button:active {
  scale: 1;
}

svg {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.sparkle path {
    color: hsl(0 0% calc((var(--active, 0) * 70%) + var(--base)));
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: center;
    fill: currentColor;
    stroke: currentColor;
    animation-delay: calc((var(--transition) * 1.5) + (var(--delay) * 1s));
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    transition: color var(--transition);
}

button:is(:hover, :focus-visible) path {
    animation-name: bounce;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    35%, 65% {
        scale: var(--scale);
    }
}
.sparkle path:nth-of-type(1) {
    --scale: 0.5;
    --delay: 0.1;
    --base: 40%;
}

.sparkle path:nth-of-type(2) {
    --scale: 1.5;
    --delay: 0.2;
    --base: 20%;
}

.sparkle path:nth-of-type(3) {
    --scale: 2.5;
    --delay: 0.35;
    --base: 30%;
}

button:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: -0.25em;
    z-index: -1;
    border: 0.25em solid hsl(260 97% 50% / 0.5);
    border-radius: 100px;
    opacity: var(--active, 0);
    transition: opacity var(--transition);
}

.spark {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    rotate: 0deg;
    overflow: hidden;
    mask: linear-gradient(white, transparent 50%);
    animation: flip calc(var(--spark) * 2) infinite steps(2, end);
}

@keyframes flip {
    to {
        rotate: 360deg;
    }
}

.spark:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    translate: -50% -15%;
    rotate: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: calc((var(--active)) + 0.4);
    background: conic-gradient(
        from 0deg,
        transparent 0 340deg,
        white 360deg
    );
    transition: opacity var(--transition);
    animation: rotate var(--spark) linear infinite both;
}

.spark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: var(--cut);
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    inset: var(--cut);
    background: var(--bg);
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: background var(--transition);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    to {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}



@supports(selector(:has(:is(+ *)))) {
    body:has(button:is(:hover, :focus-visible)) {
        --active: 1;
        --play-state: running;
    }
    .bodydrop {
        display: none;
    }
}

button:is(:hover, :focus-visible) ~ :is(.bodydrop, .particle-pen) {
    --active: 1;
    --play-state: runnin;
}

.bodydrop {
    background: hsl(
        260
        calc(var(--active) * 97%)
        6%
    );
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    z-index: -1
}



button:is(:hover, :focus-visible) {
    --active: 1;
    --play-state: running;
}


.sparkle-button {
    position: relative;
}

.particle-pen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
    -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(white, transparent 65%);
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: var(--active, 0);
    transition: opacity var(--transition);
}

.particle {
    fill: white;
    width: calc(var(--size, 0.25) * 1rem);
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(var(--y) * 1%);
    left: calc(var(--x) * 1%);
    opacity: var(--alpha, 1);
    animation: float-out calc(var(--duration, 1) * 1s) calc(var(--delay) * -1s) infinite linear;
    transform-origin: var(--origin-x, 1000%) var(--origin-y, 1000%);
    z-index: -1;
    animation-play-state: var(--play-state, paused);
}

.particle path {
    fill: hsl(0 0% 90%);
    stroke: none;
}

.particle:nth-of-type(even) {
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes float-out {
    to {
        rotate: 360deg;
    }
}

.text {
    translate: 2% -6%;
    letter-spacing: 0.01ch;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(0 0% calc((var(--active) * 100%) + 65%)), hsl(0 0% calc((var(--active) * 100%) + 26%)));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transition: background var(--transition);
}

button svg {
    inline-size: 1.25em;
    translate: -25% -5%;
}
```

JS:

```
// JavaScript used to set randomness for particles.
// Could be done via SSR

const RANDOM = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
const PARTICLES = document.querySelectorAll('.particle')
PARTICLES.forEach(P => {
    P.setAttribute('style', `
        --x: ${RANDOM(20, 80)};
        --y: ${RANDOM(20, 80)};
        --duration: ${RANDOM(6, 20)};
        --delay: ${RANDOM(1, 10)};
        --alpha: ${RANDOM(40, 90) / 100};
        --origin-x: ${Math.random() > 0.5 ? RANDOM(300, 800) * -1 : RANDOM(300, 800)}%;
        --origin-y: ${Math.random() > 0.5 ? RANDOM(300, 800) * -1 : RANDOM(300, 800)}%;
        --size: ${RANDOM(40, 90) / 100};
    `)
})
```

Comment: You've shared the code that works, but are asking about different code that doesn't work.  We'll be much more likely to be able to help you fix the code that doesn't work if you, y'know, let us see it.

Comment: (But that said, this js works by manipulating the DOM directly which will conflict with the framework. You'll need to rewrite this to use e.g. svelte's [style directive](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/style-directive) instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and *should not* use DOM querying, the elements will not exist until the component is fully mounted.

There also is no need to manually duplicate the particles (just use [`{#each}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each)) and the randomized styling can also be applied directly in the HTML.

The demo also uses CSS that targets elements outside the component, those would need to use `:global(...)`. I doubt that a button should style `body` in a real application, though.

JS and HTML can thus be condensed to:

```html
<script>
    const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
</script>

<div class="sparkle-button">
  <button>
    <span class="spark" />
    <span class="backdrop" />
    <svg class="sparkle" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M14.187 8.096L15 5.25L15.813 8.096C16.0231 8.83114 16.4171 9.50062 16.9577 10.0413C17.4984 10.5819 18.1679 10.9759 18.903 11.186L21.75 12L18.904 12.813C18.1689 13.0231 17.4994 13.4171 16.9587 13.9577C16.4181 14.4984 16.0241 15.1679 15.814 15.903L15 18.75L14.187 15.904C13.9769 15.1689 13.5829 14.4994 13.0423 13.9587C12.5016 13.4181 11.8321 13.0241 11.097 12.814L8.25 12L11.096 11.187C11.8311 10.9769 12.5006 10.5829 13.0413 10.0423C13.5819 9.50162 13.9759 8.83214 14.186 8.097L14.187 8.096Z"
        fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
      <path d="M6 14.25L5.741 15.285C5.59267 15.8785 5.28579 16.4206 4.85319 16.8532C4.42059 17.2858 3.87853 17.5927 3.285 17.741L2.25 18L3.285 18.259C3.87853 18.4073 4.42059 18.7142 4.85319 19.1468C5.28579 19.5794 5.59267 20.1215 5.741 20.715L6 21.75L6.259 20.715C6.40725 20.1216 6.71398 19.5796 7.14639 19.147C7.5788 18.7144 8.12065 18.4075 8.714 18.259L9.75 18L8.714 17.741C8.12065 17.5925 7.5788 17.2856 7.14639 16.853C6.71398 16.4204 6.40725 15.8784 6.259 15.285L6 14.25Z"
        fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
      <path d="M6.5 4L6.303 4.5915C6.24777 4.75718 6.15472 4.90774 6.03123 5.03123C5.90774 5.15472 5.75718 5.24777 5.5915 5.303L5 5.5L5.5915 5.697C5.75718 5.75223 5.90774 5.84528 6.03123 5.96877C6.15472 6.09226 6.24777 6.24282 6.303 6.4085L6.5 7L6.697 6.4085C6.75223 6.24282 6.84528 6.09226 6.96877 5.96877C7.09226 5.84528 7.24282 5.75223 7.4085 5.697L8 5.5L7.4085 5.303C7.24282 5.24777 7.09226 5.15472 6.96877 5.03123C6.84528 4.90774 6.75223 4.75718 6.697 4.5915L6.5 4Z"
        fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <span class="text">Generate Site</span>
  </button>
  <div class="bodydrop" />
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="particle-pen">
    {#each { length: 20 } as _}
      <svg
        class="particle"
        viewBox="0 0 15 15"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        style="
            --x: {random(20, 80)};
            --y: {random(20, 80)};
            --duration: {random(6, 20)};
            --delay: {random(1, 10)};
            --alpha: {random(40, 90) / 100};
            --origin-x: {Math.random() > 0.5 ? random(300, 800) * -1 : random(300, 800)}%;
            --origin-y: {Math.random() > 0.5 ? random(300, 800) * -1 : random(300, 800)}%;
            --size: {random(40, 90) / 100};
        ">
        <path
          d="M6.937 3.846L7.75 1L8.563 3.846C8.77313 4.58114 9.1671 5.25062 9.70774 5.79126C10.2484 6.3319 10.9179 6.72587 11.653 6.936L14.5 7.75L11.654 8.563C10.9189 8.77313 10.2494 9.1671 9.70874 9.70774C9.1681 10.2484 8.77413 10.9179 8.564 11.653L7.75 14.5L6.937 11.654C6.72687 10.9189 6.3329 10.2494 5.79226 9.70874C5.25162 9.1681 4.58214 8.77413 3.847 8.564L1 7.75L3.846 6.937C4.58114 6.72687 5.25062 6.3329 5.79126 5.79226C6.3319 5.25162 6.72587 4.58214 6.936 3.847L6.937 3.846Z"
          fill="black"
          stroke="black"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
        />
      </svg>
    {/each}
  </span>
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8d48a90d633c4ce79428e877fdb8e9c7?version=4.1.1)

The random helper function could also be moved to a `@const` in the `#each`, then one does not need a script tag at all. Style properties can also be set using `style:property`, though that would lead to a lot of duplication here:

```html
{#each { length: 20 } as _}
  {@const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)}
  <svg
    class="particle"
    viewBox="0 0 15 15"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    style:--x={random(20, 80)}
    style:--y={random(20, 80)}
    style:--duration={random(6, 20)}
    style:--delay={random(1, 10)}
    style:--alpha={random(40, 90) / 100}
    style:--origin-x="{Math.random() > 0.5 ? random(300, 800) * -1 : random(300, 800)}%"
    style:--origin-y="{Math.random() > 0.5 ? random(300, 800) * -1 : random(300, 800)}%"
    style:--size={random(40, 90) / 100}
  >
```